# Comprobar estado conexión a servicio Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

veréis estoy desarrollando una aplicación la cual debe disponer tanto de modo online como offline en caso de no tener activada la conexión o de no poder conectar con el servicio debido a problemas de la red, todo ello en una aplicación multiplataforma desarrollada en Xamarin-Forms para android, iOs y windows_uwp.

Comprobar si la conexión esta activa es relativamente fácil, el problema es cuando quiero comprobar si la conexión con el servicio es posible, en ese momento me salta una excepción de depuración y no es posible continuar con el programa. Me han recomendado el pluggin connectivity para esta comprobación, os dejo la parte del código encargada de ello, la comprobación de si esta conectado la realiza bien, el problema viene en la segunda parte, donde comprueba si se conecta con el host servidor.

```
            var connectivity = Plugin.Connectivity.CrossConnectivity.Current;

            if (!connectivity.IsConnected)
            {
                Clases.utilidades.MyStaticValues.hayConexionConElServidor = false;
            }
            else
            {
                  Clases.utilidades.MyStaticValues.hayConexionConElServidor = await connectivity.isReachable("nombreHost");

            }
```

En el momento en que realiza el comando situado en else, entra salta una excepcion de depuración que bloquea el programa y lo deja en pausa.
No me da ninguna excepción en concreto, ese es el problema, la excepción seria: An unhandled exception occured. Y salta una pantalla de, la aplicación se encuentra en modo interrupción, en caso de darle yo a mano a continuar, me dice que no hay código ejecutable que ejecutar

No se si alguien se ha dado con este problema.
Muchas gracias de antemano, un saludo.

---

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la excepción? ¿Cuál es la salida esperada? ¿Qué obtienes por resultado actualmente?

Comment: no me da ninguna excepción en concreto, ese es el problema, la excepción seria: An unhandled exception occured. Y salta una pantalla de, la aplicación se encuentra en modo interrupción, en caso de darle yo a mano a continuar, me dice que no hay código ejecutable que ejecutar

Comment: Las excepciones tienen un miembro llamado "Inner Exception" te recomiendo que veas el mensaje que arroja esa excepcion desde Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con Xamarin puedes utilizar prácticamente todas las clases/APIs de .NET, sobre todo si utilizas .NET Standard 2.0 o superior.

Así que podrías usar uno de estos métodos (por ejemplo) para comprobar la conexión con el servicio:

```
    public static bool HayConexion(string huesped = "http://www.bing.com")
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            using (client.OpenRead(huesped))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static bool HayConexion2(string huesped = "http://www.bing.com")
    {
        try
        {
            return new Ping().Send(huesped).Status == IPStatus.Success;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: funciona perfecto pero solo me es compatible para ios y android estas soluciones. En windows no existe la librería System.Net.NetworkInformation.ping ni  System.Net.NetworkInformation.webclient que son las que utilizan. Pero para android e ios me funciona perfecto.

Comment: Para poder utilizarlas en Windows UWP, hay que cambiar la versión mínima de Windows 10 de la aplicación, hay que elegir Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (compilación 16299) o superior. Así ya encuentra las clases. Es debido a que se necesita .NET Standard 2.0 y no es compatible con versiones anteriores de UWP.

Comment: Este cambio es posible realizarlo en las propiedades del proyecto de visual studio o en cambio solo se puede al crear un nuevo proyecto cuando te pide esas propiedades?

Comment: Se puede modificar en las propiedades del proyecto de visual studio, en el apartado Aplicación -> Destino -> Versión mínima. Al cambiarlo, se recarga el proyecto y ya encontrará las clases con: using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

Comment: He hecho el cambio que me comentaste y la he liado, ahora el proyecto de windows uwp me aparece como no disponible

Comment: Arreglado, con dar botón derecho en el proyecto de UWP y darle  a cargar proyecto apareció de nuevo, que susto... Muchísimas gracias enserio, ya funciona, muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegro que funcione, se debería haber actualizado solo con darle a propiedades -> Aplicación y en Destino cambiar versión mínima.

Comment: Hola! una pregunta... Yo uso el primer método que describe @WP8_CT peroo hay veces que me manda al catch con el error de TimeOut, ¿eso es por que pierde conexión? La verdad me demora mucho en darme una respuesta cuando eso pasa y pues aunque pongo un mensaje al usuario de espera pues si es tedioso que se quede colgada por eso :/